Next.js on vercel won't update
I developed Next.js CRUD app with microCMS.
My app completely work on my local side. But unfortunately when uploading my app to vercel, it won't work correctly. Every time I update values, it won't change like below.
Here's my code of update.js and index.js.
I added some update query on createClient.
lib/client.js
import { createClient } from 'microcms-js-sdk';

export const client = createClient({
  serviceDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MICROCMS_SERVICE_DOMAIN, 
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MICROCMS_API_KEY,
  retry: true,
  customFetch: (input, init) => {
    const newInput = new URL(input)
    const time = new Date()
    newInput.searchParams.set('cacheclearparam', `${time.getMinutes()}`)
    return fetch(newInput.href, init)
  },
});

pages/update.js
import Link from "next/link";
import { client } from "@/libs/client";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Update ({ blog }) {
  const router = useRouter()
  const id = blog.id;
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(blog.title);
  const [content, setContent] = useState(blog.content);

  const remove_html = text => {
    return text ? text.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, '') : null;
  }

  async function update(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    client.update({
      endpoint: "blogs",
      content: {
        title: title,
        content: content,
      },
      contentId: id
    }).then((res) => {
      if (res.status === 401) {
        alert("編集ができませんでした。")
      } else {
        alert("編集されました。")
        router.push(`/`)
      }
    })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className='main'>
        <h1 className=''>編集ページ</h1>

        {/* TOPに戻るボタン */}
        <div className="top">
          <Link href="/" className="">
            <button className="">Topに戻る</button>
          </Link>
        </div>

        <div className="contents">

            <div>
                <form onSubmit={ update }>
                  <div>
                      <h2>タイトル</h2>
                      <input name="title" type="text" defaultValue={blog.title} onChange={(event) => setTitle(event.target.value)} />
                  </div>
                  <div>
                  <h2>コンテンツ</h2>
                      <textarea name="content" defaultValue={remove_html(blog.content)} onChange={(event) => setContent(event.target.value)} ></textarea>
                  </div>
                <button type="submit">
                    <p>登録する</p>
                </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const data = await client.get({ endpoint: "blogs" });

  const paths = data.contents.map((content) => `/blog/${content.id}/update`);
  return { paths, fallback: false };
};

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const id = context.params.id;
  const data = await client.get({ endpoint: "blogs", contentId: id });

  return {
    props: {
      blog: data,
    },
  };
};

pages/index.js
import Head from "next/head";
import Link from "next/link";
import styles from "@/styles/Home.module.css";
import { client } from '@/libs/client'
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function Home({ blog }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  async function deleteItem(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
    const id = formData.get('id');
    client.delete({
      endpoint: 'blogs',
      contentId: id,
    })
      .then((res) => {
        alert("正常に削除されました。")
        router.push(`/`)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        alert("削除できませんでした。"+err)
      })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <div id="new-blog">
          <Link href="/blog/create" className="">
            <button className="">ブログを作成</button>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div id="blog-list">
          {blog.map((blog) => (
            <div className={styles.div}>
              <ul className={styles.ul}>
                <li className={styles.li} key={blog.id}>
                  <Link href={`/blog/${blog.id}`}>{blog.title}</Link>
                  <Link href={`/blog/${blog.id}/update`} className="">
                    <button className="">編集</button>
                  </Link>
                  <form onSubmit={ deleteItem }>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value={blog.id} />
                    <input type="submit" value="削除" />
                  </form>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  )
}

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const data = await client.get({
    endpoint: 'blogs',
  })

  return {
    props: {
      blog: data.contents,
    },
  }
}





You need to invalidate your cache. You're probably going to need to read these multiple times - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching & https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating

Thanks. I read what you suggested many times. I could not figure out how to invalidate cache.

I'm confident your problem is cache invalidation. The solution is in the existing documentation. However, it's quite nuanced and took my co-worker and me two days to figure out. Unfortunately, because the specifics are unique to your setup, I can't provide a direct solution. But once you navigate through those details, it should work as expected.

Got it. Anyway, I'm going to read it until I understand. As you said earlier, it's so complicated. Thanks for the advice.
